# Java: Finding neighbours of a start coordinate (0,0)

Tags: java, position, coordinates, neighbours

I've been having an issue figuring out how I can search arround a coordinate to find its neighbours. It will make more sense when you see the picture.

I have 7 hexagons and they all have respective coordinates where the center one is (0,0). I wish to create a method in which I can add all neighbour hexagons to an arraylist, but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how I can determine that the added hexagon is in fact an neighbour.

Picture here: [image]

Example: (Reference to picture)

I wish to know which neighbours the hexagon on position (0,-1) has. By looking at the picture I can see it has (1,0) , (0,0) and (-1,-1). But how would I loop through this and find its neighbours in java code?

Comment: There really isn't much info going on here. If you just have 7 hexagons, just hardcode the values and stick them in the method of the hexagon object. Do some boundary checks on the generated coordinates and you're good. If your grid is more complicated than that, the please add that into the question.

Comment: [This page](https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/) has some useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make some assumptions and try to present an answer. Please comment if something changes or doesn't sit right.

From the looks of it your grid is square. What I mean by that, both the X and the Y coordinate are specified in the same range. Consider the following class:

```
public class HexagonalGrid {
  // Helper class Cell
  public static class Cell {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Cell(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }
  }


  // ranges are
  // x -> [-width, width]
  // y -> [-height, height]
  private int width;
  private int height;

  public HexagonalGrid(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }

  public ArrayList<Cell> getNeighbours(Cell target)  {
    ArrayList<Cell> neighbours = new ArrayList<>();

    // These coordinates are predictable, so let's generate them
    // Each immediate 
    for (int x_offset = -1; x_offset <= 1; x_offset++) {
      for (int y_offset = -1; y_offset <= 1; y_offset++) {
        // No offset puts us back at target cell so skip
        if (x_offset == 0 && y_offset == 0) { 
          continue;
        }

        // Generate the cell with the offset
        int x = target.x + x_offset;
        int y = target.y + y_offset;

        // Check validity against bounds
        if (isValidCoordinate(x, y)) {
          // Add valid neighbour
          Cell neighbour = new Cell(x, y);
          neighbours.add(neighbour);
        }
      }
    }

    return neighbours;
  }


  private boolean isValidCoordinate(int x, int y) {
    // Enforcing the ranges specified above
    return -width <= x && x <= width
        && -height <= y && y <= height;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the enum Direction approach

```
public enum  Direction {
    UP(1, 0),
    RIGHT_UP(1, 1),
    RIGHT_DOWN(-1, 1),
    DOWN(-1, 0),
    LEFT_DOWN(-1, -1),
    LEFT_UP(1, -1);

    private final int dy;
    private final int dx;

    Direction(int dy, int dx) {
        this.dy = dy;
        this.dx = dx;
    }

    public int getDy() {
        return dy;
    }

    public int getDx() {
        return dx;
    }


    public Direction next() {
        return values()[(ordinal() + 1) % values().length];
    }

    public Direction opposite() {
        return values()[(ordinal() + values().length / 2) % values().length];
    }
}
```